# How to add spacing and rounded corners to a tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to add some margin to my tableview. Right now it looks like this:

[image: current]

But, I would like it to look like this:

[image: want to look like]

I tried insetting, but that didn't work right. I'm new, so not quite sure how the CGRect works.

I am writing this in swift.

Comment: May I know why haven't you tried grouped tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Try self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero